# Trying to serialize an object compactly using Castor

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, marshalling, castor

I'm using Castor to write out a map of user ID's to time intervals. I'm using it to save and resume progress in a lengthy task, and I'm trying to make the XML as compact as possible. My map is from string userID's to a class that contains the interval timestamps, along with additional transient data that I don't need to serialize.

I'm able to use a nested class mapping:

```
...
<field name="userIntervals" collection="map">
 <bind-xml name="u">
  <class name="org.exolab.castor.mapping.MapItem">
   <field name="key" type="string"><bind-xml name="n" node="attribute"/></field>
   <field name="value" type="my.package.TimeInterval"/>
  </class>
 </bind-xml>
</field>
...
<class name="my.package.TimeInterval">
 <map-to xml="ti"/>
 <field name="intervalStart" type="long"><bind-xml name="s" node="attribute"/></field>
 <field name="intervalEnd" type="long"><bind-xml name="e" node="attribute"/></field>
</class>
...
```

And get output that looks like:

```
<u n="36164639"><value s="1292750896000" e="1292750896000"/></u>
```

What I'd like is the name, start, and end of the user in a single node like this.

```
<u n="36164639" s="1292750896000" e="1292750896000"/>
```

But I can't seem to finagle it so the start and end attributes in the "value" go in the same node as the "key". Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One (slightly-flawed) approached I considered was having a custom `FieldHandler` for the `value` - but then I have to put the start and end time in a single attribute. A bit more compact than I want ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am answering my own question here, since there is a solution that does exactly what I want, and there's actually an error in the explanation at http://www.castor.org/xml-mapping.html#Sample-3:-Using-the-container-attribute - the *container* attribute is exactly what's needed here.

Changing one line in the mapping:

```
<field name="value" type="my.package.TimeInterval" container="true"/>
```

did *exactly* what I wanted, it didn't create a subelement for the value, just mapped the fields into the existing parent element. Since then, I've used this quite a few times to map multiple-value classes into their parent.

The error of course is the documentation states you do this by setting the *container* attribute to *false*. Of course, it should be *true*.

Answer (score 1):

Nash,
I think to arrange the castor mapping is bit tricky.
 If you want to have structure like

```
<u n="36164639" s="1292750896000" e="1292750896000"/>
```

Then you need to create a new pojo file where it will be having
 all the three fields Key,intervalStart,intervalEnd.
And let the File name as KeyTimeInterval
And map it like the below.

```
 <field name="userIntervals" collection="map">    
  <class name="org.exolab.castor.mapping.MapItem">   
    <field name="u" type="my.package.KeyTimeInterval">
      <bind-xml name="u" node="element"/>
    </field>             
   </class>        
 </field>



<class name="my.package.KeyTimeInterval">  
  <field name="key" type="String">
        <bind-xml name="n" node="attribute"/></field> 
    <field name="intervalStart" type="long">
        <bind-xml name="s" node="attribute"/></field>   
     <field name="intervalEnd" type="long">
      <bind-xml name="e" node="attribute"/></field>   
 </class>
```

Comment: That was precisely the sort of outside-the-box thinking I needed. I just iterated the map and converted it to that list of pojos (and the reverse when I reloaded). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to use `location` on `s` and `e`. Try this:-

```
...

<class name="my.package.TimeInterval">
   <map-to xml="ti"/>
   <field name="intervalStart" type="long">
      <bind-xml name="s" location="u" node="attribute"/>
   </field>
   <field name="intervalEnd" type="long">
      <bind-xml name="e" location="u" node="attribute"/>
   </field>
</class>
```

Comment: I gave this a try; it just added another child-node `u` underneath the `t` node. I thought maybe `location` was XPath and I could move the current node back to the parent with `..`, and that just created a strange `<..>` child-node :(